# SqlServer:Select and group by Month

Tags: sql

I want to write a SQL to count the sales of my last six months, just like the code below.

```
SELECT
    MONTH (pc.createTime) AS MONTH,
    SUM (partsModelSum) AS totalSum
FROM
    partscontractlinkmodel AS pl
RIGHT JOIN partscontract pc ON pl.partsContractID = pc.partsContractID
AND pc.companyID = 8
AND pc.createTime BETWEEN '2013/11/01 00:00:00'
AND '2014/04/30 23:59:59'
WHERE
    pl.partsModelID = 21028
GROUP BY
    MONTH (pc.createTime)
ORDER BY
    totalSum DESC
```

AND results is：

```
month   totalSum
4       24
```

But the problem the problem arises,No sales record month does not appear in the query results, **I want there is no sales records in results and a value of 0**

like this：

```
month   totalSum
4       24
3       0
2       0
1       0
12      0
11      0
```

**So,How to modify sql solve my problem  ;)
thanks**

Comment: If you have the time to create a Calendar table it would make queries like these a breeze. Because you can stand up results on a  date range between startdate and enddate whether you have aggregate data there or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some data every month, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT MONTH (pc.createTime) AS MONTH,
       SUM(CASE WHEN pl.partsModelID = 21028 THEN partsModelSum END) AS totalSum
FROM partscontract pc LEFT JOIN
     partscontractlinkmodel  pl
     ON pl.partsContractID = pc.partsContractID AND
        pc.companyID = 8 AND
        pc.createTime BETWEEN '2013/11/01 00:00:00' AND '2014/04/30 23:59:59'
GROUP BY
    MONTH(pc.createTime)
ORDER BY totalSum DESC;
```

If this doesn't work, you need to generate the list of months using a subquery or CTE.

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of month from a table or sub query. Left join the months table/query and  partscontract via month(createTime) and month from table/sub-query. Left join partscontract and partscontractlinkmodel like what you did. See below for sample:

;WITH CTE_Month
as
(
SELECT 1 as MonthN
UNION
SELECT 2 as MonthN
UNION
SELECT 3 as MonthN
UNION
SELECT 4 as MonthN
UNION
SELECT 5 as MonthN
UNION
SELECT 6 as MonthN
UNION
SELECT 7 as MonthN
UNION
SELECT 8 as MonthN
UNION
SELECT 9 as MonthN
UNION
SELECT 10  as MonthN
UNION
SELECT 11 as MonthN
UNION
SELECT 12 as MonthN
),
SELECT
    N.MonthN AS MONTH,
    SUM (ISNULL(partsModelSum,0)) AS totalSum
FROM
    CTE_Month M
    LEFT JOIN partscontract pc ON  MONTH (pc.createTime) = N.MonthN
    LEFT JOIN partscontractlinkmodel AS pl
      ON pl.partsContractID = pc.partsContractID
      AND pc.companyID = 8
      AND pc.createTime BETWEEN '2013/11/01 00:00:00'
      AND '2014/04/30 23:59:59'
WHERE
    pl.partsModelID = 21028
GROUP BY
    N.MonthN
ORDER BY
    totalSum DESC

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temp table of list of months and use it in the join...may be something like this...

```
SELECT
    MONTH (pc.createTime) AS MONTH,
    SUM (partsModelSum) AS totalSum
FROM
    (select 1 monthNum union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 10 union select 11 union select 12 ) MonthList
    left join partscontract pc ON MonthList.monthNum = MONTH(pc.createTime)
    left join partscontractlinkmodel AS pl ON pc.partsContractID = pl.partsContractID
            AND pc.companyID = 8
            AND pc.createTime BETWEEN '2013/11/01 00:00:00'
            AND '2014/04/30 23:59:59'
WHERE
    pl.partsModelID = 21028
GROUP BY
    MONTH (pc.createTime)
ORDER BY
    totalSum DESC
```